# Assigning values of an array in a for loop java

Tags: java

Im still starting out in java - and any guidance would be great on this. I'm basically hoping to create an array, then assign values to that array in a for loop. The code I have at the moment is:

```
int i;
int[] testarray = new int[50];

for (i = 0; i <=50; i++) {  
testarray[i]=i;
}
```

All i wanna do is make an array with each entry the number of the iteration (using this method)
I know its really simple, but I feel as if I have missed something important during learning the basics! 
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Everything is fine except the stop condition:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
```

Since your array is of size 50, and indices start at 0, the last index is 49.

You should reduce the scope of `i`, avoid hard-coding the length everywhere (don't repeat yourself principle), and respect the camelCase naming conventions:

```
int[] testArray = new int[50];

for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {  
    testArray[i]=i;
}
```

Comment: Read the error messages and try to understand what they mean, instead of just treating them as an error flag. The error message probably said: ArrayOutOfBoudsException, and probably told you the index you tried to access, but was out of bounds.

Answer (score 6):

Your array has 50 elements, and your loop goes over 51 elements (0 to 50).

Just change the code to:

```
int[] testarray = new int[50];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {  
    testarray[i] = i;
}
```

or better:

```
int[] testarray = new int[50];

for (int i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++) {  
    testarray[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can move the declaration of i into the for loop, rather than outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use length of the array instead of hard-coding 50.

```
for (i = 0; i <testarray.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Create a function that takes two numbers as arguments (num, length) and returns
    // an array of multiples of num until the array length reaches length.
    package ArrayPractice;

    public class Question1 {

        //Creating array method
        public int[] arrayofMultiples(int number, int demo) {
            int[] testing = new int[demo];
            int y = 1;
            int z = number;
            for (int i = 0; i < testing.length; i++) {
                number = z * y;
                testing[i] = number;
                y++;
            }
            return testing;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Question1 question1 = new Question1();
            // Creating an array to get the get values of array method
            int[] t1 = question1.arrayofMultiples(17, 6);
            for (int i : t1) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Program to input elements in an array in java using for loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);

// code starts here

        int length;
        length=a.nextInt();    
        int [] arr = new int[length];    
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            arr[i]=a.nextInt();    
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){   
            System.out.println(arr[i]);   
        }
    }
}
```