# Array - Loop - Generate random number in Java

Tags: java

I have to write a program that generate random integers from 0 to 9 for 1000 times and count repeated numbers. So output should be like:

0 used 123 times,
1 used 89 times,
2 301 times,
.
.
9 used 23 times

I must use math.random for this. I can generate numbers but how can I use array and loop for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning values of an array in a for loop java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495143/assigning-values-of-an-array-in-a-for-loop-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `java.util.Random`, you don't need array and loop.
Try this.

```
System.out.println(new Random().ints(1000, 0, 10)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> String.format("%d used %d times", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

result

```
0 used 109 times, 1 used 97 times, 2 used 81 times, 3 used 107 times, 4 used 121 times, 5 used 100 times, 6 used 97 times, 7 used 96 times, 8 used 80 times, 9 used 112 times
```

Comment: Nice demonstration of the power of streams and lambdas. Plus 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you will get your desired output:

```
**import** java.util.HashMap;  
**import** java.util.Map;

public **class** RandomCounting  
{

    static **Map**<Integer,Integer> result=new **HashMap**<Integer,Integer>();
    static int[] a=new int[10];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int value=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            //System.out.print(value+" ");
            switch(value)
            {
            case 0:result.put(0,a[0]++);break;
            case 1:result.put(1,a[1]++);break;
            case 2:result.put(2,a[2]++);break;
            case 3:result.put(3,a[3]++);break;
            case 4:result.put(4,a[4]++);break;
            case 5:result.put(5,a[5]++);break;
            case 6:result.put(6,a[6]++);break;
            case 7:result.put(7,a[7]++);break;
            case 8:result.put(8,a[8]++);break;
            case 9:result.put(9,a[9]++);break;
            }
            //System.out.print(value+" ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" used "+result.get(i)+" times");
        }
    }
}
```